# Can I use regime-switching when bootstrapping relatively few data (<50 samples)?

Tags: bootstrap, monte-carlo, fitting, curve-fitting, small-sample

Consider a large set of data, each with a series of 25-50 independent, non-negative observations and the following characteristics: a) most series have positive values only, b) some series have <10 observations whose value is zero, and c) some series have <10 observations whose value is non-zero.

I am attempting a parametric bootstrap of each data set in Python, in order to then simulate a large number of scenarios from the resulting densities. For strictly positive data series, a straightforward fit works well, resulting in minimal error. For data with some zero values, I use a regime-switching model, such that the value of the function is determined by f(x) with probability p and 0 with probability (1-p).

The challenge arises with the third category: how do you go about fitting a sample whose values are mostly zero? I figure maybe a highly-skewed, long-tailed distribution ought to do a reasonable job, but even the best fits produce lousy results.

For what it's worth, to capture average and worst-case behaviors, I score my fits based on the following methodology: a) calculate quantiles in 0.05 intervals for the empirical data; b) calculate the corresponding theoretical quantiles for each candidate distribution, c) calculate the average absolute percent error between (a) and (b), d) calculate the maximum error between (a) and (b) such that:

Error = 0.75 * Absolute Percent Error + 0.25 * Maximum Absolute Percent Error

Your help and time are immensely appreciated!